# Disable a certain cell in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using a fullcalendar in my portal, and I need to disable a certain cell where it will not be clickable anymore and the user can't create an event in that cell.

Plus I want to color the disabled slot with a unique color.

Answer (score 0):

I know how you can get a cell by date and change her color.

You should view this: https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/pull/26

All you need to do is search the plugin for this line:

```
cell.find('div.fc-day-number').text(date.getDate());
```

And then, you should insert the line below:

```
cell.attr('data-date', $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, "yyyyMMdd"));
```

After that, you can get a cell by date, using something similar to this:

```
$(".fc-widget-content[data-date='20120105']").addClass("disabled-slot");
```

And put the color you want on the cell.

To disable the cell, maybe you could then do something like this (not tested):

```
$(".fc-widget-content[data-date='20120105']").draggable({ disabled: true });
```

Comment: @AdilMalik Week view doesn't have cells for each hour of each day but, with some changes on the code, you could put it working too. Here's an example I did some time ago: [http://www.albinstrutora.pt/#!student](http://www.albinstrutora.pt/#!student). If you inspect this code, you will see that each hour of each day have a cell and that it is painted via css class.

Comment: Is it really fullCalendar ?? It looks a lot different. Can you please provide the code? So I can see how are you adding the cells for each time slot?

Comment: I can't put all the code in a comment but, if you open a question on stackoverflow and give me the link to it, I will be glad to help you out.